# Flash As3: Process and return data from a child class

Tags: actionscript-3

I am stuck here. I have a child class that I want to use mainly to format a string variable called mystring, whose value changes according to the object clicked. I need to pass mystring into the child class and format it there. The formatted string is then returned to the parentclass for placement. I just couldn't get the code right. Can anyone please help?

```
Main Class: package {   public class parentclass extends Sprite{
        public var mystring:String="";

        public function parentclass () {
            mysting="good"
                         ---
                 }
           }
```

Child Class:

```
package {
    public class childclass extends Sprite{


        public function childclass () {
            var mycapstring:String=
                        //do these 3 things: 
                        //1. get the value of mystring from parentclass 
                        //2. format mystring 
                        //3. return formatted string to parentclass 
                }

         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, when you reference something as a `child class` it implies that it extends the `parent class`.  In your case, you are simply using one class inside another (composition).

Is there a reason you don't want to just have a function that does this for you as part of parentclass?

```
package {   
    public class ParentClass extends Sprite{

        protected var mystring:String = "";

         public function ParentClass () { 
             this.mysting = "good"
         }

         public function format():String {
             return this.mystring + " | " + this.mystring;
         }
    }
}
```

Is there something else going on here?  Why does `childclass` need to extend `Sprite`, is it a `DisplayObject`?  You will need to give more context as to what you are trying to do for me to help any further.

Comment: Thanks, sberry. The reason why I want to have it outside the parentclass is because the process that the function does is a long one and I need to use it in other projects. What this does is actually to get filter the "mystring" value from an xml loaded into the parent class. I just gave the code as an example, the childclass doesn't need to extend Sprite.